# Swift read data from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, nsdictionary

I am using this code to read data from `NSDictionary`:

```
let itemsArray: NSArray = response.objectForKey("items") as! NSArray;
let nextPageToken: String = response.objectForKey("nextPageToken") as! String

var videoIdArray: [String] = []

for (item) in itemsArray {
      let videoId: String? = item.valueForKey("id")!.valueForKey("videoId") as? String
      videoIdArray.append(videoId!)
}
```

But when i `items` or `nextPageToken` are not exist i get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any idea why? how i can fix it?

Comment: Remove ; (semicolon) in first line. @MTA

Comment: `NSDictionary objectForKey:` returns `nil` if the key doesn't exist. I'm pretty sure keys are case-sensitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check dictionary value is empty or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473841/how-to-check-dictionary-value-is-empty-or-not)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. You are trying to force unwrap an optional that can be nil. Never use forced unwrapping, if you are not sure whether the data will be available or not.
2. You are using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:` for retrieving data from a dictionary. Use [objectForKey: instead of valueForKey:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey) for getting data from a dictionary.

You can fix the crash by:

```
let itemsArray: NSArray?   = response.objectForKey("items") as? NSArray;
let nextPageToken: String? = response.objectForKey("nextPageToken") as? String

var videoIdArray: [String] = []
if let itemsArray = itemsArray
{
    for (item) in itemsArray
    {
       let videoId: String? = item.objectForKey("id")?.objectForKey("videoId") as? String
       if (videoId != nil)
       {
          videoIdArray.append(videoId!)
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i'm using the same code for retrieving object value from a NSDictionary, but it shows an error. Is there any new update in swift 3?