# Variable username is not updated after call to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
var username: String? = nil
self.ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let usersProfile = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let userProfile = usersProfile![userID] as? NSDictionary
    username = userProfile!["username"] as! String

}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
print(username)
```

Why is the variable `username` not updated in the end?

Comment: Try this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367183/swift-read-data-from-nsdictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367183/swift-read-data-from-nsdictionary)

Comment: Do some searching on the meaning of "asynchronous". You are printing `username` long before it is set.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

```
  var username: String? = nil

    self.ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

       if let usersProfile = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, let userProfile = usersProfile![userID] as? NSDictionary, let name = userProfile!["username"] as? String {
username = name
}

    }) { (error) in
       print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    print(username)
```